# Communication protocol using netcat

Tags: linux, bash, network-protocols, netcat

I need to create a way to communicate commands and transfer files from a host server to a development board.

- The only access to the board is via the host server (wired Ethernet connection).
- Both the host server and the board are running Linux.
- I have the ability to change the Linux environment on the board.
- I DO NOT have the ability to change the host server environment.
- I DO NOT know which users need to connect to the board.
- The connection between the host server and the board does not need to be secure.

Right now, I'm using netcat for my needs but have run into reliability issues - Could someone point me to some tools that are better suited to my needs and perhaps higher performance, please?

My current solution:

A script is constantly running on the board:

```
while [ 1 ] ; do
    # Start a netcat server, awaiting a file.
    nc -l -p 1357 > file.bin

    # Acknowledge receipt of file.
    status=fail
    while [ ${status} -ne 0 ] ; do
        status=$(echo 0 | nc <host_ip> 2468 2>&1)
    done

    # Wait for a command.
    nc -l -p 1357 -e /bin/sh

    # Acknowledge receipt of command.
    status=fail
    while [ ${status} -ne 0 ] ; do
        status=$(echo 0 | nc <host ip> 2468 2>&1)
    done
done
```

The only way users have access to the board is through a script on the server:

```
# Send over a file.
cat some_file.bin | /bin/nc -w 10

# Wait for acknowledge.
if [ $( nc -l 2468 ) -ne 0 ] ; then
    exit # Fail
fi

# Send a command.
echo "<some_command>" | nc -w 10 <board ip> 1357

# Wait for acknowledge.
if [ $( nc -l 2468 ) -ne 0 ] ; then
    exit # Fail
fi
```

The reason I'm using netcat right now is that I don't know of any way to use SSH or SCP without a password given that:

- I can't generate an SSH key for everyone that needs access to the board, especially since I don't know who will be using it.
- I can't install sshpass or expect since I don't have control of the server.

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SSH with host-based authentication. Then you would not need those script and simply use SSH and SCP normally, without the need for passwords nor user keys.

With host-based authentication, any user connecting from a predefined set of machines (here it would be the host) is automatically authenticated on the target machine (here the board).

You need to modify the `SSH` server configuration on the board, and the `SSH` client configuration on the host (which you can do without the need for a root access).

Here is a [tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Host-based_Authentication) that should get you started.

Note that if encryption is not mandatory and performance is of issue, you can use the same host-based authentication scheme for [`RSH` access](http://people.redhat.com/kzak/docs/rsh-rlogin-howto.html).

Comment: doesn't the OPs statement 'I DO NOT have the ability to change the host server environment.' preclude 'modifying ..  SSH client configuration on the host'? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter  If the OP is able to run `ssh board` on the host he should also be able to run `ssh -o HostbasedAuthentication board`.